# Some computers ask to download a file instead of showing the xhtml page

Tags: xhtml

Some of our workstations will ask to download a file instead of show the xhtml page when they try to view our company's website. This happens on firefox, IE 8, IE 9 and chrome but this isn't happening to every workstation. The only information I can find on the web that talks about browsers prompting to download a file instead of displaying xhtml pages say that it is a server side problem and it happens to every computer that tries to view the page and may or may not happen to all browsers. My situation is different since this does not happen on all computers and you can have two identical computers running IE9 at the same level of windows updates and it happens to one and not the other.

the doctype of the web page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: IE8 can't use XHTML files, so it's possible that those problematic IE9's are operating in IE8 mode or compatibility mode. Check if changing them to real IE9 mode helps.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that all browsers fail to dislay the file on certain computers, but that on certain other computers, all browsers are doing OK?